# Using tableau to compute entropy from a estimated probability distribution

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following situation: after sniffing multiple packets from a WLAN, I consider the random variable X with values given by the protocol number and probabilities given by the number of packets with that protocol number over the total of the packets (that is, I poorly estimate the probability that a given protocol occurs on the network).

This gives me something like this:

[image: Plot]

These values are calculated by using

```
COUNT([Protocol]) / TOTAL(COUNT([Protocol]))
```

Now, however, I want to convert these values into information content (which is just applying -LOG(, 2) to the expression above) and add a line showing the entropy of the "source".

If I were to do this, an easy way would be to just do:

```
SUM(EXP((-1) * x) * x)
```

Where x is -LOG(,2) of the first expression. However, Tableau complains about this being a double aggregate. Is there any other way to calculate this?

Comment: Why do you need the SUM() in the second calculation?

Comment: Because that is the definition of entropy, it is the sum over the range of the random variable of the value's probability multiplied by the logarithm of the value's probability

Comment: Then change SUM to WINDOW_SUM to create a table calculation, and set "compute using" for that calculation to your protocol number field

Comment: How so? I don't understand

Comment: Alright, your trick worked!. Want to post it so I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: Glad to help.  I added some explanation in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change SUM to WINDOW_SUM to create a table calculation, and set "compute using" for that calculation to your protocol number field

If you want to understand more, study how table calculations work. In a nutshell, the sum() calculation is performed by the external data source or database in response to the query sent by Tableau. Then the aggregated query result is returned to Tableau as a summary table. Table calcs such as Window_Sum() operate on that summary table.

The "compute using" directive instructs Tableau on how to partition the summary table; that is to define the scope of the window used to compute Window_Sum()

Answer (score 0):

I find the following sentence very useful for understanding why we are interested in "Entropy in Tableau":

"The basic intuition behind information theory is that learning that an unlikely event has occurred is more informative than learning that a likely even has occurred."

- Page 73, Deep Learning, 2016